# How to delete a long substring from a string without leaving empty lines?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a vcard string : I want to delete a line from this string , for example line related to TEL but when i use **replace method** , an empty line is left , how to delete the full line without leaving an empty line ?

```
vcard = """ BEGIN:VCARD
            VERSION:3.0
            UID:00000xcdfgedgrerfgrg
            N:LastName;FirstName;;;
            TEL;CELL:00000000 EMAIL:yx@company.com
             END:VCARD
        """
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
import re
vcard = """ BEGIN:VCARD
        VERSION:3.0
        UID:00000xcdfgedgrerfgrg
        N:LastName;FirstName;;;
        TEL;CELL:00000000 EMAIL:yx@company.com
         END:VCARD
    """
re.sub(".*TEL.*\n?","",vcard)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'\n'.join([x for x in vcard.split() if 'TEL' not in x])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delete the entire line, then you have to replace *the entire line*, including leading spaces and the newline the end:

```
vcard = vcard.replace('            TEL;CELL:00000000 EMAIL:yx@company.com\n', '')
```